# Error:(93, 34) error: constructor Request in class Request cannot be applied to given types reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Tags: java, android, firebase

i am currrently working on a firebase project and i am stuck with this error 
it keeps showing this error during compilation.

`Error:(93, 34) error: constructor Request in class Request cannot be applied to given types;
required: Uri,int,String,List<Transformation>,int,int,boolean,boolean,boolean,float,float,float,boolean,Config,Priority
found: String,String,String,String,List<Order>
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length`

Here is my Cart Class

> public class Cart extends AppCompatActivity {
>
> ```
> RecyclerView recyclerView;
> RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
> FirebaseDatabase database;
> DatabaseReference requests;
> TextView txtTotalPrice;
> FButton btnPlace;
> List<Order> cart = new ArrayList<>();
> CartAdapter adapter;
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);
>
>     // init firebase
>     database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
>     requests = database.getReference("Requests");
>
>     //Init
>     recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listCart);
>     recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
>     layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
>     recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
>
>     txtTotalPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);
>     btnPlace = (FButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlaceOrder);
>
>     btnPlace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View view) {
>             showAlertDialog();
>         }
>     });
>
>     loadListFood();
> }
>
> private void showAlertDialog() {
>
>     AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Cart.this);
>     alertDialog.setTitle("One More Step!");
>     alertDialog.setMessage("Enter your address: ");
>
>     final EditText edtAddress = new EditText(Cart.this);
>     LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
>             LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
>             LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
>     );
>
>     edtAddress.setLayoutParams(lp);
>     alertDialog.setView(edtAddress);//Add edit Text to alert dialog
>     alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp);
>
>     alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
>             //Create new Request
>             Request request = new Request(
>                     Common.currentUser.getPhone(),
>                     Common.currentUser.getName(),
>                     edtAddress.getText().toString(),
>                     txtTotalPrice.getText().toString(),
>                     cart
>             );
>             //Submit to Firebase
>             //We will using System.CurrentMilli to key
>             requests.child(String.valueOf((System.currentTimeMillis()))).setValue(request);
>             //Delete Cart
>             new Database(getBaseContext()).cleanCart();
>             Toast.makeText(Cart.this, "Thank you , Order Placed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>             finish();
>         }
>     });
>
>     alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
>             dialogInterface.dismiss();
>         }
>     });
>     alertDialog.show();
>
> }
>
> private void loadListFood() {
>
>     cart = new Database(this).getCarts();
>     adapter = new CartAdapter(cart, this);
>     recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
>
>     //calculate total price
>     int total = 0;
>     for (Order order : cart)
>         total += (Integer.parseInt(order.getPrice())) * (Integer.parseInt(order.getQuantity()));
>     Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US");
>     NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
>
>     txtTotalPrice.setText(fmt.format(total));
>
> } }
> ```

and here is my constructor class Request 
package game.bakarunlimited.com.androideatit.Model;

> import java.util.List; /**  * Created by gaurang on 9/23/2017.  */
>   public class Request {
>
> ```
> private String phone;
> private String name;
> private String address;
> private String total;
> private List<Order> foods;
> // list of food Order
>
> public Request(){
>
> }
>
> public Request(String phone, String name, String address,String total, List<Order> foods) {
>     this.phone = phone;
>     this.name = name;
>     this.address = address;
>     this.total = total;
>     this.foods = foods;
> }
>
> public String getPhone() {
>     return phone;
> }
>
> public void setPhone(String phone) {
>     this.phone = phone;
> }
>
> public String getName() {
>     return name;
> }
>
> public void setName(String name) {
>     this.name = name;
> }
>
> public String getAddress() {
>     return address;
> }
>
> public void setAddress(String address) {
>     this.address = address;
> }
>
> public String getTotal() {
>     return total;
> }
>
> public void setTotal(String total) {
>     this.total = total;
> }
>
> public List<Order> getFoods() {
>     return foods;
> }
>
> public void setFoods(List<Order> foods) {
>     this.foods = foods;
> } }
> ```

[image: here the screenshot of error]

Comment: Please use the `{}` editor button for code, not the block quote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check your `Cart` class and make sure you've imported the correct `Request` (just make sure the package name matches where you have your `Request` class at the top of the file)
The reason I say this is because your current `Request` class should be taking in `String, String, String, String, List<Order>` to create the object however it's throwing an error saying its expecting `Uri,int,String,List,int,int,boolean,boolean,boolean,float,float,float,boolean,Config,Priority` which makes me think you are using the wrong import for `Request`